# Lambda function not authorized to perform apigateway:GET

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to invoke a function with AWS-SDK from Gateway api but I receive the error below.

The execution role has a policy with execute-api:* as action and resoure is '*'.

And the code is:

```
const restApi = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apiGateway.getRestApi({restApiId: myRestApi}, function(err, data) {
```

The error:

```
2020-06-06T08:58:47.741Z    d3e08e04-095c-41ec-bbe6-69344d53854c    INFO    getRestApi err AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::123412341234:assumed-role/mydev-LambdaExecutionRole/mydev-api-FooFunctionsStack-AddFooFunction-123ASDF is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1::/restapis/xxx111yy
    at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
```

The network settings should be fine, lambda is within VPC but it has public subnet to connect services outside from it. Previously it didn't and the apiGateway.getRestApi was timed out.

Role policy:

```
LambdaExecutionRole: 
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      RoleName: 'MyRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: 
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: lambda-execution-policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                  - rds:*
                  - rds-data:* 
                  - ses:SendEmail
                  - ses:SendRawEmail 
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - s3:*
                  - execute-api:*
                Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Please include the IAM role policy for the Lambda function

Comment: How did you deploy your function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> lambda is within VPC but it has public subnet to connect services outside from it

Unfortunately the error is **not about public access** to the API gateway, which is required for getting information about the api.

Instead, the error is about your [lambda's execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) `mydev-LambdaExecutionRole` not having permissions to execute `GET` method on the `xxx111yy` resource.

Your permissions `execute-api:*` are for **invoking** the api. Your lambda function should have permissions for `apigateway:*` which is used to **get information about api**. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "apigateway:GET",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are **two ways** to rectify the issue:

- add the lambda's execution role ARN into [api getaway  resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html) with the required permissions
- or add required permissions to your lambda's execution role itself.

Comment: this works for me! thank you! I feel the first approach, adding lambda role ARN to api's api gateway resource policy is easier. from second way, it might require several permissions that execute api requires.